# Add div box to list li

Tags: html, css

```
<ul>
    <li><div style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px; display: inline"></div>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
</ul>
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cb8j7/)**

why in this example div is not visible? How can i add box with background-color in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: inline` will not display unless it contains some kind of contents. You'd need to either

`display: inline-block;` or

```
<div style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px; display: inline">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is empty. It becomes visible if you add some text inside.

```
<ul>
    <li><div style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px; display: inline">test</div>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all there's no text in your `<div>` so you should do it like this :

You need to place the word `aaa` between your `<div>` tags

`<li><div style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px; display: inline">aaa</div></li>`

moreover you don't need any `display: inline;` property here you can simply do it like this :

[**My fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cb8j7/5/)

And if you need all the `<li>` elements inline than you need to give `display: inline;` to your `<li>` and `display: inline-block;` to your `<div>` element also like this : [**My fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cb8j7/7/)

Comment: @arttronics didn't noticed (s) ..hehe thank you very much.. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the W3C validator div inside list is perfectly fine. You have to give some text in div. So that you can view the div.